# jquery UI library as comprehensive as extjs, dojo/dijit, YUI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, extjs, dojo, yui

jQuery is most popular JavaScript library definitely (see the tag list on your right hand side). However, the "official" UI library, jQuery UI, provides far less widgets than some other libraries (extjs, dojo/dijit, YUI for examples) out-of-box.

Are there any other UI libraries built on jQuery compare those "other libraries"? Preferably free for non open source projects.

Comment: jQuery, Dojo and YUI serve different audiences.  jQuery is for small-download, light-JavaScript pages.  YUI is at its heart a UI library for web UI's.  Dojo is for large-scale enterprise-level web applications.  You should be using the right tool for the right task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext JS is easily the most powerful.. another advantage of Ext JS is that it can be used along with jQuery and Prototype... so you can have the best of both. Plus ext js has now redesigned it's architecture to a more `MVC` style framework, so its more flexible..  BUT it's license is at best dodgy.. so be sure to go through the licensing before you decide to use Ext JS.

Check out the [comparisons at wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)

Comment: Ext js have everything that has jquery and prototype, so no need to include them .

Comment: Yes.. i know.. but if there are some custom components already built by the the user then he can use that along with ext js instead of rebuilding them.

Comment: I'm confused with the license. Is it free for non-open-source but non-commercial projects, say, my personal project for fun but with potential growing into a profitable one in the future?

Comment: If you are planning to make money from site and not from the ads you need to buy license from them

Comment: I've no legal expert.. but this is what i understood from it.. "you can use it for free for ONLY if your source code is available to the client to change. For everything else, it's not free."

Comment: read this.. http://www.sencha.com/legal/open-source-faq/

Comment: If you site has financial income you need to buy their license.

Comment: Seems that Varun is right. Even if there is no financial income, as long as the project is put in public and used by others, one must either purchase a commercial license or disclose the source code. I'll probably go with Dojo due to this license issue.

Comment: and the worst part is that all code that uses extjs code is also under GPL license, even that must be provided. That means that even server side code is required to be open source.

Answer (score 1):

I think that most powerfull Extjs. I dont know good Jquery library that includes main components

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of UI/Widget libraries built on jQuery. Two of the bigger ones are:

http://www.kendoui.com/

http://wijmo.com/

If you are comfortable enough with another library, extjs is super powerful.

Comment: Definitely Wijmo answers the question. It has some commercial Widgets, but the open source ones really improve on the jQueryUI default components.